# FlowPane and Positioning

Tags: java, javafx-8, panes

Is it possible to use a flowpane in the following way?
Have two components (img/label) aligned to the left and then multiple buttons on the right. Example:

```
    +----------------------------------------------------------------+
    | +------+ +----------+                          +-----+ +-----+ |
    | |  Img | | Text...  |                          | btn | | btn | |
    | +------+ +----------+                          +-----+ +-----+ |
    +----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am adding the buttons for design / ease of use but am running into a brick wall. I would prefer not to have to change the 'holding panel'.

If not can it be simulated in css (float?)

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a way to do this using a `FlowPane`. It's kind of contrary to the idea of a "flow"... In JavaFX, CSS is basically used for the look of the nodes, not for layout (as it is in HTML). This probably works best using a combination of either an `AnchorPane` or `BorderPane` and a couple of `HBox`es. But maybe someone else can see a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FlowPane`can set margins. [Here](https://gist.github.com/flasheater/00e675029df3aa771f76) is an example that shows how to calculate the width of the margin so that the buttons are right aligned.

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener( ( observable, oldWidth, newWidth ) ->
{
  final double spacerMargin = newWidth.doubleValue()
      - scene.getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream().mapToDouble( node -> node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() ).sum();
  FlowPane.clearConstraints( btn3 );
  FlowPane.setMargin( btn3, new Insets( 0, 0, 0, spacerMargin ) );
} );
```

You basically subtract all the widths of the children of the FlowPane from the width of your scene.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is!

```
myFlow.add(griddy); // this gridlayout contains img and text
myFlowcontainer.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0))); // Creating a space between. 
The actual size will be defined by you
myFlow.add(griddy2); // The other element with the btn btn
```

That should seal the deal ;)

Comment: `Box.createRigidArea(...)` doesn't create a JavaFX `Node`, it creates a Swing component.

Comment: Okay i didn't see the JavaFX tag. Now i do :p. 
That is correct it doesn't create JavaFX Node. 
I just wrote down a gernal approach :p